# Why does OpenZeppelin implement increaseAllowance and decreaseAllowance functions differently in their ERC20 contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, security, openzeppelin-contracts

This is copied from their ERC20 contract from github (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol):

```
function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()] + addedValue);
    return true;
}

function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
    uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
    require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
    unchecked {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
    }
return true;
}
```

Why would they not be implemented the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [PR #2669](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/2669) where those changes were made they mention [Issue #2665](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/2665). In that issue a [comment by vladyan18](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/2665#issuecomment-837028875) points that using unchecked *reduces gas usage at deployment by 1723*.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think the other ideas that switching the position of a condition check conditions reduces gas cost are interesting.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen It is a little odd but is isn't surprising because solidity developers are usually cautious about optimizations.